# Determining the asymptotic behavior of some function of random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Consider a series of random matrices $X_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ consisting of i.i.d. entries, each with zero mean and variance $1/m$, and let $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ be two deterministic (or random and independent on $X$) vectors, say with bounded norm.

I want to find the structure of some "nice"/"simple" "limit" function, $f_n$, of the following term
$$
a_n^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n-f_n\to0
$$ 
almost surely, as $n,m\to\infty$ with fixed ratio.

**EDIT**: Due to Ofer's answer and comments I will consider some specific choice of $a_n$:
$$
\frac{1}{n}w_n^TX_n^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n-f_n\to0
$$ 
Since $w_n^TX_n^T = \sum_{i=1}^mw_{i}x_i^T$ where $x_i$ is $i$th raw of $X_n$, we can write that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}w_n^TX_n^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^mw_{i}x_i^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n
\end{align}
We know that $X_nX_n^T = \sum_{i=1}^mx_ix_i^T$. Let $\left[X_nX_n^T\right]_i = X_nX_n^T-x_ix_i^T$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}w_n^TX_n^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^mw_{i}x_i^T\left(X_nX_n^T+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^mw_{i}\frac{x_i^T\left(\left[X_nX_n^T\right]_i+I_n\right)^{-1}b_n}{1+x_i^T\left(\left[X_nX_n^T\right]_i+I_n\right)^{-1}x_i}
\end{align}
Now, since $x_i$ is independent on $\left(\left[X_nX_n^T\right]_i+I_n\right)^{-1}$, we know that (a.s.)
$$
x_i^T\left(\left[X_nX_n^T\right]_i+I_n\right)^{-1}x_i-\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)\to0
$$
where $\rho$ is the limit density of eigenvalues of $XX^T$. The same is true for the numerator. So, the speculation is that $f_n$ behaves like 
\begin{align}
f_n &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^mw_{i}\frac{x_i^Tb_n\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)}{1+\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)}\\
&=\frac{\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)}{1+\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)}\frac{1}{n}w_n^TX_n^Tb_n
\end{align}

**Update**: Numerical calculations suggests that the above "limit" is not true, although, I can't really say that I completely understand where the rub is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a_n=b_n$ with $\|a_n\|=\|b_n\|$,
the result is standard (and can be found for example in papers of Bai and Silverstein, usually as a technical lemma in the appendix...): 
let $\rho$ be the limit density of eigenvalues of $XX^T$ (the Pastur-Marchenko law). Then
the limit you seek is asymptotically the normalized trace of $(XX^T+I)^{-1}$, i.e., $A:=\int (1+x)^{-1} \rho(dx)$.

If $a_n\neq b_n$ it requires a bit more work, but the answer should be $A\cdot \langle a_n,b_n\rangle$. The reasoning is similar: the expression you have is $\sum \lambda_i 
\alpha_i \beta_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are the coefficients of $a_n$ in the eigenbase of 
$XX^T$. This will concentrate near its mean (to prove that, use results on the eigenvectors as in Silverstein's paper from the mid 90's on eigenvectors of covariance matrices; everything is much simpler in the Gaussian case), which will give the expression I wrote.

Comment: Thanks. The second case is what I need. Actually, I also thought that $A\cdot \langle a_n,b_n\rangle$ is the limit, but, numerical calculations (using MATLAB) do not agree with that. Generally speaking, if we look at $(1/n)\text{trace}(V(...)^{-1})$, and if we assume that $V$ is **non-negative and Hermitian** then it can be shown that the limit is $A\cdot \text{trace}(V)$. But, if $V$ is not necessarily non-negative or Hermitian, then again MATLAB... 
I will check it again.

Comment: In general of course you do not have a decomposition. However, let's see in your case. Let's take $b_n=\alpha a_n+b_n'$ where $b_n'$ is orthogonal to $a_n$. To make notation simple, assume the norm of $a_n$ and of $b_n'$ to be $1$. You are trying to compute $a_n^T V b_n'$ where $V$ is your matrix of the form $UDU^T$. At least in the Gaussian case, $U$ is Haar distributed and independent of $D$. Let $W$ be the unitary matrix such that $Wa_n=e_1$ and $Wb_n'=e_2$. Then  you are trying to compute the (1,2) element of $WUD(WU)^T$. But $WU$ is again Haar distributed, so law is same as

Comment: (1,2) element of $UDU^T$, which is $\sum_j U_{1j} U_{2j} D_j$. But this has mean $0$ and is of order $1/\sqrt{n}$. Are you sure about your matlab simulation?

Comment: OK, I checked it again, and now it works as you said. My silly mistake was that in my problem I forgot that $a_n$ **depends** on the matrix $X$ (actually very strongly). Particularly, $a_n$ is given by $a_n^T = w^TXX^T$ where now $w$ is some random and $independent (of the other random quantities) vector. Is there any hope to find the limit in such a case? Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: I edited the question, according to my last comment.

Comment: you mean $a_n^T=w^T X^T$ or $a_n^T= w^T XX^T$?  In both case the answer can be computed, but it depends which one you care about...

Comment: Actually, I need both of them :-) . But, I believe (or maybe hope) that after understanding one of them, the other will be easier to obtain (?)

Comment: The version with $w^T XX^T$ is trivial: write $w^TXX^T=w^T (XX^T-I)+ w^T$. Now use the previous answer for the second term (first term is trivial).

Comment: The version with $w^TX^T$ is also simple: Write $X=UD^{1/2}V$ with $D$ diagonal (the singular value decomposition) so that $XX^T=UDU^T$ and $(XX^T+I)^{-1}=U(D+I)^{-1}U^T=UBU^T$. Now, $w^TX^T(XX^T-I)^{-1}=w^TVDBU^Tb_n$. Now apply my previous answer.

Comment: Regard the second version, $X$ is not square, and so the SVD is $X = USV$ where $S$ is rectangular. But, it is not really a problem if we change the notations from $D^{1/2}$ and $D$ to $D$ and $DD^T$, respectively. Can you please say little more about how you invoke your previous answer to finish the calculation (did you meant the answer in the comments with the Gaussian assumption?)?

Comment: The Gaussion assumption was to illustrate the point, it is not really needed and the answer will be the same. In any case, what you have is a diagonal matrix (DB) multiplied left and right by vectors that are randomly rotated, in this case by (essentially independent) rotations. This is very similar to the original problem.

Comment: It is a bit awkward, but, I'm struggling with the calculation of the limit. What we want to find is the limit of $w^TVD^T(DD^T+I)^{-1}U^Tb$ where now $w$ is of size $m\times 1$ and $b$ is $n\times 1$, and the matrix $D^T(DD^T+I)^{-1}$ is rectangular. I'm not sure how to apply the previous result. I will be very glad if you will elaborate little more about it, or, maybe refer me to a book or article (I tried to find such similar technical calculations in your book, but I didn't find any).

Comment: In continuation to my question in my previous comment, is the wavehanding-calculations in my original message (after the edit) are reasonable?

Comment: I suggest email for further communication. My answers related to the square (n=m) case. In the rectangular case you need to adapt, but D can still be taken diagonal.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Isn't Bai and Silverstein limited for vectors $a_n,b_n$ with zero mean? Specifically, I am interested in a similar case, where $\{X_n\}$ is a Gaussian vector with independent entries, fixed variance, and different means ($X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\sigma^2\boldsymbol{I})$), and $\{A_n\}$ are a sequence of Gaussian $n\times p$ matrices, independent of $X_n$. I want to show that $1/n X_n^T(1/nA_nA_n^T)^{-1}X_n\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[1/n X_n^T(1/nA_nA_n^T)^{-1}X_n]$ in probability. I am having trouble deriving results for the biased case.

Comment: Posted a separate question here :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467239/convergence-in-probability-of-quadratic-form-with-positive-mean