# Convergence in probability of quadratic form with positive mean

Tags: random-matrices, limits-and-convergence, quadratic-forms

Let $\boldsymbol{X}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a sequence of Gaussian random vectors with independent entries, such that $X_{n,i}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$ (that is, all entries of the $n$th vector have the same variance but different means, for a fixed known sequence $\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^\infty)$.
Let $\boldsymbol{A}_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a sequence random psd matrix such that
$\lambda_\text{max}(\boldsymbol{A_n})\triangleq \lambda_{\text{max},n}\rightarrow a$, almost surly and  $\mathbb{E}\lambda_{\text{max},n}\rightarrow a$, and
$\lambda_\text{min}(\boldsymbol{A_n})\triangleq \lambda_{\text{min},n}\rightarrow b$, almost surly and  $\mathbb{E}\lambda_{\text{min},n}\rightarrow b$, for fixed deterministic constants $a$ and $b$.

Assume that
$$\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{X}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{X}_n\rightarrow d,$$
for a constant $d$. Does this imply that
$$\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{X}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{X}_n\rightarrow d, \text{in probability} ??$$

I know that when the means are zero and the maximal eigenvalues of $A_n$ are surly bounded, this is true (in the stronger a.s sense), e.g, [Lemma 7.6 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03003.pdf). But I am having hard time to prove this for my more delicate case.

**Edit:**

Maybe a better way to formulate this question is to define $\boldsymbol{V}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\boldsymbol{X}_n$. Then, we have that $\mathbb{E}\boldsymbol{V}_n\triangleq \boldsymbol{\nu}_n\rightarrow \boldsymbol{0}$ but also
$\boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\boldsymbol{\nu}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i^2$ and $\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{V}_n)= \sigma^2$. Then the question is whether
$$\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{V}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{E}\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{V}_n$$
in probability. In my case I have that $\mathbb{E}\boldsymbol{A}_n=d\cdot\boldsymbol{I}$, therefore:
$$ \mathbb{E}\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{V}_n =\frac{\sigma^2+\boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\boldsymbol{\nu}_n}{n}\text{trace}(\mathbb{E}\boldsymbol{A}_n),$$
So maybe this makes things easier.

To show some of my efforts, assume that $\lambda_{\text{max}}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)\leq C$ (this is a stronger constraint than I have in the original question) for any $n$ and some constant $C<\infty$, moreover, $\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)=d\cdot\boldsymbol{I}$ and $1/n\cdot\text{trace}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)\rightarrow 1/n\cdot\text{trace}(\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)) = d$ almost surely. Then, from [Lemma 7.6 in Dobriban and Wager](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03003.pdf) we have
$$(\boldsymbol{V}_n-\boldsymbol{\nu}_n)^T\boldsymbol{A}_n(\boldsymbol{V}_n-\boldsymbol{\nu}_n)\rightarrow \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\text{trace}(\boldsymbol{A}_n).$$
Also:
$$(\boldsymbol{V}_n-\boldsymbol{\nu}_n)^T\boldsymbol{A}_n(\boldsymbol{V}_n-\boldsymbol{\nu}_n)=\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{V}_n -2\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{\nu}_n+\boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{\nu}_n $$
If I can show that
$$ \boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{\nu}_n\rightarrow \boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)\boldsymbol{\nu}_n$$
in probability, and also
$$ \boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{\nu}_n\rightarrow \boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)\boldsymbol{\nu}_n$$
in probability, I will get
$$\boldsymbol{V}_n^T\boldsymbol{A}_n\boldsymbol{V}_n \rightarrow \frac{\sigma^2+\boldsymbol{\nu}_n^T\boldsymbol{\nu}_n}{n}\text{trace}(\boldsymbol{A}_n)$$
Which is what I need in this case.

Comment: Take $\sigma^2=0$ to see that what you ask for can't be true.  For example, take $\mu_i=1$ for $i=1,\ldots, n/2$ and $0$ otherwise, and consider the matrix $A_n$ which is diagonal, and with probability $1/2$ has $+1$ in the top $n/2$ entries and $0$ else, while with probability $1/2$ has $+1$ only on the bottom $n/2$ entries. Then $d=1/2$ but there is no convergence in probability. More asumptions are needed on $A_n$ to say something meaningful...

Comment: Isn't $d=0$ in this case? since I have the $1/n$ factor? And in this case, I get sure convergence of $1/n X_n^TA_nX_n$ to zero, isn't it?
 Anyway, in my case $A_n$ are inverse Wishart matrices of degree $p=\gamma n$ (that is, $A_n=(1/n F_nF_n^T)^{-1}$, with $F_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ having iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries). Also, my $\mu_i$ are all strictly positive and so is $\sigma^2$. Via numerical simulations, it seems that there is convergence in probability, but I am having some problems with proving it mainly due to the non-deterministic bound on the eigenvalues of $A_n$.

Comment: I have edited the question to add some details about my previous attempts

Comment: $d$ is not 0 in the example I gave, but the matrix is of course very far from wishart. Note that in that example, $trace(A_n)=n/2$.

Comment: Right, I missed the fact that $n/2$ of the means are $1$. So it is not true in general, but simulations suggest that it is true for inverse-wishart. Any direction for the proof?